Need help with understanding PDE in relation to traffic flow (conservation of mass) and use of method of characteristics to solve this PDE.
Here is equation of traffic flow:
$dρ/dt + d(ρu(ρ))/dx = 0.$
We have $ρ = ρ(x, t)$ - a vector field of densities of cars on a 1-dimensional road. Any point in space at any given time have some density from 0 to $ρ_{max}$. My understanding that this is a $N/(m*s)$, a number of cars passing through some part of a road per unit of time. ρ * length of the road * time must give a number of cars, passed through?
$u = u(x, t)$ or in this simplified sense $u = u(ρ)$ is a vector field of car velocities. We use $u = u(ρ)$ since we assume that car speed depends only on distance between cars (when there are no cars ahead of you, you accelerate to the max speed, and when there is cars bumper to bumper you stuck in the traffic with zero speed). This must be meters/second.
I understand why this equation must be equal to 0: because amount of cars is constant, how many cars have driven in from one side of the road - same number must have drive out from the other side.
What I don't get is how these terms relate to each other:

Speed $m/s$ divided by meters is $1/s$;

Density: $N/m*s$, divide by seconds, and we get $N/m*s^2$, or $1/m*s^2$.


So one part is $1/s$, the other is $1/m*s^2$. Clearly something isn't right with my understanding.
The second question is how to solve such equation with method of characteristics, and, more importantly, what does characteristics mean in relation to this equation? I know definition, but I don't get the sense of it.

Is $u(\rho)$ a known (given) function ? Or is it an unknown function that you expect to find ?

@JJacquelin: $u(\rho)$ is given, and you seek $\rho(x,t)$.

Let's use meters and seconds as units. Then the density $\rho$ is just the number of cars per meter, which causes the unit of $\rho_t$ to be number/(m · s), which matches with the unit of $(\rho u)_x$ since that's ((number/m) · (m/s)) / m = number/(m · s) too.
I won't try to answer the question about characteristics, since I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. I think that perhaps that question is too broad for this forum – after all, the answer might take up a whole chapter in a textbook (such as Whitham's Linear and Nonlinear Waves, just to mention a well-known one). So maybe you could try to narrow it down to some more specific point that you don't understand, and ask it as a separate question?

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial (\rho u)}{\partial x}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+(u+\rho\frac{du}{d\rho})\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}=0$$
Since $u(\rho)$ is a known function the function $\quad v(\rho)=u(\rho)+\rho\frac{du}{d\rho}\quad$ is a known function.
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+v(\rho)\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}=0$$
Solving this PDE thanks to the method of characteristics leads to the general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation ;
$$\rho=F\big(x-v(\rho) t\big)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function if no initial condition is specified.
$$\boxed{\rho=F\Big(x-\big(u(\rho)+\rho\frac{du}{d\rho} \big) t\Big)}$$
Solving the implicit equation for $\rho(x,t)$ requires at least to know :

The function $u(\rho)$ on explicit form.

The initial condition.


But this isn't always sufficient. All the implicit equations cannot be inverted on the form of a combination of presently available standard functions. This depends on the kind of function $u(\rho)$.
Without giving the function $u(\rho)$ and the initial condition in the wording of the problem one cannot go further.

As expressed by @JJacquelin there is not much you can do without knowing $u(\rho)$. However, the most common choice is something like
$$j(\rho)=\rho ~u(\rho)=4\rho(1-\rho)$$
Where $j$, the "mass flux" of cars, takes its maximum value of $1$ when the road is half-full, and decreases symmetrically in both directions about that maximum. It is a crude but fairly representative model of real traffic flow.
In that case JJacquelin's solution becomes
$$\rho(t,x)=\rho_0\big(x-4(1-2\rho(t,x))t\big)$$
Where $\rho_0(x)=\rho(0,x)$ is the initial condition. A common choice of the initial condition is in which cars are stopped at a red light at $x=0$, i.e
$$\rho_0(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x < 0 \\ 0 & x\geq 0\end{cases}$$
When the light turns green at $t=0$, this creates an expansion wave centered at the origin: INTERACTIVE PLOT
You will see behavior like this in the real world when cars stop at a red light, you will see the brake lights the stopped cars turn off in a steady wave traveling backwards from the stopping point.
